# Required: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<java.lang.String>; found java.lang.String

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb

I have a problem when setting the values in JAVA web services. I have done the web service client to be setting the values but I am getting the error messages  Required: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement; found java.lang.String .

I have  developed web service client stubs and below is sample scripts from the stubs

```
 Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
    // Extract the endpoint interface, the service "port".
      ObjectFactory  daget = service.getPort(ObjectFactory.class);  
      ComBdata  NewComdata = (ComBdata) daget.createProd();
         NewComdata.setNumberID(rd.getString(1));
```

**From client stubs generated**

```
 public void setNumberID (JAXBElement<String> value) {
    this. numberID = value;
    }
```

How can I solve this error? I am new to JABX

Comment: Don't know from your code what `rd.getString(1)` is, I guess it returns `String`. But your method `setNumberID` expect a parameter of type `JAXBElement`.

Comment: How to do you set or configure JAXBElement  then supply it ??

Answer (score 0):

This method creates a JAXBElement with a certain value:

```
<T> JAXBElement<T> wrap( String ns, String tag, T o ){
    QName qtag = new QName( ns, tag );
    Class<?> clazz = o.getClass();
    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    JAXBElement<T> jbe = new JAXBElement( qtag, clazz, o );
    return jbe;
}
```

Your call will be

```
JAXBElement<String> jbw = wrap( ?, ?, rd.getString(1) );
```

but I can't tell you namespace or element tag.